# database disjoint relationship described

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have an disjoint ER diagram in which my table "Employee" is disjoint to table "Salaried Employee" and table "Hourly Employee"

How do i perform a relationship between these tables in Microsoft Access?

My current table is as follows:

"Employee"
Employee_ID (primary key)
Firstname
Lastname

"Salaried Employee"
Annual_salary

"Hourly Employee"
Hourly_rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an EmployeeID in the Salaried Employee and Hourly Employee tables.

You could then use a JOIN:

```
SELECT Employee.Firstname, [Salaried Employee].Annual_salary, [Hourly Employee].Hourly_rate
FROM Employee
JOIN [Salaried Employee] ON [Salaried Employee].EmployeeID = Employee.Employee_ID
JOIN [Hourly Employee] ON [Hourly Employee].EmployeeId = Employee.Employee_ID
```

Comment: in this case the EmployeeID used in Salaried Employee is a foreign key? not a primary key right?

Comment: Correct. I would design the database so the Salaried Employee table has a SalaryID (Primary Key) and an EmployeeID field as a foreign key.  The Hourly_Employee table should have a HourlyID field (Primary Key) and a EmployeeID field as a foreign key.

Comment: The SalariedID and HourlyID fields are redundant here.  I would omit them, and make EmployeeID the primary key of all three tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use EmployeeID as the primary key in all three tables, and define a one-to-one relationship between [Employee] and [Salaried Employee], and another one-to-one relationship between [Employee] and [Hourly Employee].  This reduces your storage overhead.